# composite, dissolve function isn't working properly on AWS Lambda

Tags: imagemagick, aws-lambda, graphicsmagick

I am trying to make small service to composite image to another image.

Here is my source code:

```
gm(srcImage)
    .composite(overlayImage)
    .dissolve('20')
    .geometry('+0+0')
    .write(output, (err) => {
      console.log(err | ouput);
    })
```

This source code is working properly on my local environment (Node 8.10, MacOS high Sierra). 
But not working as I expected on AWS Lambda.

This is result image after run on local environment :

https://ibb.co/iOuZAd

This is result image after run on AWS Lambda environment :

https://ibb.co/iLg33y

======

ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2016-06-22 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org

Node 8.10

gm module v1.23.1

======

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Version 6.7 is around 5 years old, so try updating that. I wouldn't be surprised if the issue is related to colourspace and whether it is treated as RGB or sRGB. Maybe try adding `-colorspace sRGB` or `-colourspace RGB` as the first parameter after loading your input images.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I solved problem by using newer ImageMagick version.